# Calling timer event Listener early in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, timer, callback

I have the code:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(milliseconds, repititions);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, callback);
timer.start();
```

and if a user click I want to call the callback early.  Is there was a way to either force the timer to finish immediately, or stop it and send the `TimerEvent.Timer` on my own?

I'm looking for something simple like the tween classes `fforward()`.

*EDIT*

The Solution was

```
timer.dispatchEvent(new TimerEvent(TimerEvent.TIMER));
```

I was trying to do `timer.dispatchEvent(new TimerEvent("TIMER"));` which doesn't work.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your asking how can you invoke the event handler before the event is dispatched? Simply call the event handler and parse `null` to the event argument like so: `onTimerComplete(null);`.

Comment: I no longer have access to the callback, just the timer, so I need to dispatch the event or make time speed up :P

Comment: The reason your orig dispatch worked is that events work by string names.  TimerEvent.TIMER is a const string == "timer" (see http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/TimerEvent.html).  Also, you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var evt:TimerEvent = new TimerEvent(TimerEvent.TIMER);
timer.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have button call a function in my example i call it onDoEvent.
onDoEvent will then call the timer event callback using the proper "CLICK" event.

```
import fl.controls.Button

var milliseconds:int = 3000;
var repititions:int = 0;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(milliseconds, repititions);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimerEvent );


var btn_start:Button = new Button( );
btn_start.label = 'start';
btn_start.x = 0;
btn_start.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onStart );
this.addChild( btn_start );
function onStart( e:Event ):void{
    timer.start();
}

var btn_stop:Button = new Button( );
btn_stop.label = 'stop';
btn_stop.x = 150;
btn_stop.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onStop );
this.addChild( btn_stop );
function onStop( e:Event ):void{
    timer.stop();
}



var btn_doEvent:Button = new Button( );
btn_doEvent.label = 'Trigger Event';
btn_doEvent.x = 300;
btn_doEvent.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onDoEvent );
this.addChild( btn_doEvent );
function onDoEvent( e:Event ):void{
    onTimerEvent( new TimerEvent("CLICK") );
}




function onTimerEvent(e:TimerEvent){
    trace('TimerEvent was triggered');
}
```

Comment: Here you are just calling a function you created and have access to on a click... I am trying to make the timer call a function that's listening for it's TimerEvent.Timer

Comment: it does I named the function onTimerEvent

Comment: try the code. create a new flash as3 project drag a button from the components panel into the library and then code and paste this code into the actions panel

Comment: This code has buttons for stopping and starting a timer, when you click on the event button, you are just calling a function that prints timerEvent was triggered... but if you had a 

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent){ callback(); });

the callback function won't be called, because no TimerEvent.Timer is being propogated through the timer

Comment: timer.dispatchEvent(new TimerEvent(TimerEvent.TIMER));

Comment: Exactly by doing timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent){ callback(); }); you are creating a nameless function. With the function being nameless there is only one way to access it and that is with the listener that created it.

Comment: The only way to do it is to extract the function and give it a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(milliseconds, repititions);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, callback);
timer.start();

function callback(e:TimerEvent):void{
   //to do what
}
```

to call simpliest way, just call the function like this.

```
callback(null);
```